# determine CVS / git differences

Tags: git, cvs

I don't want to know the differences between the two VCS but I've one CVS repository with a bunch of modules and one git repository with another set of equivalent submodules.

For each of those modules: I want to build a list of the differences per file between the two repositories (or modules/submodules)

If both git and CVS share exactly the same content this list should be empty, but in other cases I'm looking for a list with the corresponding deltas. What was changed on one side and what on the other? What files were deleted... etc

What is the best way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

If the path of each submodule is the same in the CVS and git repo, you can use `git --work-tree=... status` or `git --work-tree=... diff` to quickly see the difference between:

- the git index
- the CVS path used as a git working tree.

Something like:

```
git submodule foreach 'git --work-tree=/path/to/cvs/repo/$path diff`
```

See the [`git submodule foreach`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) command

```
foreach
```

> Evaluates an arbitrary shell command in each checked out submodule.
>   The command has access to the variables `$name`, `$path`, `$sha1` and `$toplevel`
>
> `$path` is the name of the submodule directory relative to the superproject

Answer (score 1):

1. checkout git repo to folder a
2. checkout cvs repo to folder b
3. delete all files from folder a
4. copy all files from folder b to a
5. git diff

Comment: That is why I suggest the `git --work-tree=/...` approach: no need to copy over files from one repo to the other.